# AppScript - Writing to a specific cell

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am taking my first steps in any sort of coding language, been proficient with Excel/Sheets for a while and looking to start automating a few small things to make mine and my teams' life a little easier. Currently I have successfully written it to copy my Template sheet and rename the template to the selected name from a dropdown menu on a tab called "Create Sheet" (Cell J21) but I am struggling with getting it to rename cell B1 on the new sheet to the selected name as well, here is what I have for copying the template. I tried a few things I found through Google and YouTube last night for also writing to B1 on the copies of Template but was unsuccessful.

```
function CreateSheet() {
  
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var TemplateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  var newSheet = TemplateSheet.copyTo(ss);
  var SheetName = ss.getRange("J21").getValue();

  // Makes the new sheet the active sheet and renames it to the name in cell 'Create Sheet'J21 //
  ss.setActiveSheet(newSheet);
  ss.renameActiveSheet(SheetName);


  // Renames cell B1 on the new sheet to the name in 'Create Sheet'J21 //
  // ** this is where I am needing help **
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify the value of **B1** of the newly created sheet with the value of 'Create Sheet'!J21 on the same spreadsheet, then you can use this:

```
let createSheetJ21 = ss.getSheetByName('Create Sheet').getRange('J21').getValue();
ss.getSheetByName(newSheet).getRange('B1').setValue(createSheetJ21);
```

But since you already set the newSheet as the active one, you can use `getActiveSheet` alternatively.

```
ss.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue(createSheetJ21);
```

You can also use the whole A1 Notation on `getRange` (including the sheet name), see sample below:

```
let createSheetJ21 = ss.getRange('Create Sheet!J21').getValue();
// Append `!B1` to newSheet variable   
ss.getRange(newSheet + '!B1').setValue(createSheetJ21);
```

#### EDIT:

- Integrating it with your current script, it should look like the one below. This contains some modifications/optimizations since there are some misunderstandings on your current one. See comments below:

```
function createSheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Template');
  const createSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Create Sheet');
  const sheetName = createSheet.getRange('J21').getValue();
  
  // No need to assign since copyTo doesn't return anything
  // By default, this creates a sheet 'Copy of <name of sheet copied>'
  templateSheet.copyTo(ss);

  // setActiveSheet takes Sheet object as input (not sheetName)
  // we need to create Sheet object first using its default name 'Copy of <name of sheet copied>'
  const createdSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Copy of Template');
  ss.setActiveSheet(createdSheet);
  ss.renameActiveSheet(sheetName);
  
  // setValue the cells
  createdSheet.getRange('B1').setValue(sheetName);
}
```

#### Sample:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [getRange(a1notation)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation)
- [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range?hl=en#setvaluevalue)
- [setActiveSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setactivesheetsheet)
- [copyTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, there are a couple other places I am needing to write the name to as well elsewhere, but didnt want to overwhelm the initial question. Looking at that I'll be able to adapt it to accomplish my other goals.

Just out of curiosity, as I stated this is my first venture into any sort of coding project outside of basic Excel/Sheets functions. Would you have written this a different way? Is there a more "proper" way I should be writing Javascript?

Comment: Hi @GusTheAnt, no problem. Are those cells adjacent to each other or separate? if those are all adjacent (2d matrix or 1 column/row), then a single command should do and it will be `setValues`. If not (separate and different cells), you would need to use multiple `setValue`s.

Comment: Hi @GusTheAnt, If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Hi @GusTheAnt, check this [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245400/room-for-octavia-sima-and-gustheant), let's have a chat

Comment: Hi @GusTheAnt, I have added some improvements to your actual script and integrated it to my post above. See **EDIT** section where it includes some explanations on some lines.

Comment: There is only one other spot on a different sheet that the value in 'Create Sheet'!J21 needs to go now that I double checked, but that example combined with `setValues` makes enough sense I can forge my way through. Again, thank you.

Comment: Refreshed and saw your latest edit, thank you again. That looks a lot more efficient. This project is small, but gotta learn to walk before I can run.

Your latest edit has also taken me down the road to learning the differences between const, var, and let, so this was immensely helpful. I was unaware as I only started this yesterday afternoon lol.

Comment: You are welcome @GusTheAnt, you already are learning so that's the first step. Feel free to post another question here if you have any difficulties. Try to browse first if there are similar questions and if not, post it as a new question.